# Send current Login name to apex item

Tags: authentication, oracle-apex

I want to assign current login `username` into an apex 5.0 item, how can i do it.

I did below but it is not working.

`dynamic action = 'on page load'    action = set value  Set Type = Static Asisgnment    Value = &APP_USER;   also   :APP_USER.    Affected Elements = :P12_USERNAME;`

Comment: You need not to start your tittle with the technology. Use the tags instead.

Answer (score 1):

Values like this can be baked into the page render, no dynamic action necessary. Though I suspect your problem was all you needed to supply for affected elements was the item name, no punctuation.

If you want to assign it as a default value just on the UI item, then use the 'Default' option, below source details. Use Static Value:

```
&APP_USER.
```

If you need the value to also be in session state, then use a 'before region' computation on the item, but it only needs to be the same static value.

If you're not sure what session state is, then please read the concepts manual, then read a few blogs and presentations on that specific topic.
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/doc.50/e39147/concept.htm#HTMDB03000

If you ever need to refer to it within PL/SQL, don't use substitution strings, this opens your application to SQL Injection security issues. Use this instead:

```
:P12_ID := :APP_USER;
```

There are a list of built in substutition strings here
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/doc.50/e39147/concept_sub.htm#HTMDB25032

Comment: How to put this value to a form value when the form is created using oracle apex app builder?

Answer (score 0):

with following code i solved my problem.

1: create a PROCESS and set the EXECUTION POINT to AFTER HEADER, selected process TYPE to PL/SQL, with the below code.

Declare

username varchar2(20) := '&APP_USER.';

BEGIN
  :P12_ID :=  username;
END;

Comment: using substitution strings inside quotes is not advised. http://www.explorer-development.uk.com/securing-vulnerability-exploits-apex-part-3/